# Not hearing all sounds with new headset. Issue with headset or computer?

Tags: audio, headset, gaming

I recently purchased a **Plantronics GameCon 380** headset for gaming, mostly for LOTRO. They have 3.5mm plugs for headphones and microphone. When plugged in, I am only hearing background (environmental) sound, not speaking voices.

**If I pull the plug halfway out, I can hear everything.**

Before I return them, can anyone explain why this is happening? Mostly, I want to know if the problem is with the headset or the computer. I have 2 computers, and the headset acts the same way on both computers, but both computers have the same case, so I'm thinking it could also be an issue with the audio jacks on the case.

Comment: you have to test the headphones on another computer to be sure

Answer (score 0):

I was going to say "driver issues" , but you said that when you pull the plug half-way it works. That can mean one of the two options:

- The plug, the wire connecting it to the headset itself or the plug inside the headset is damaged. I bet it's the wire, it may got out of place and on of the inner wires got detached.
- The 3.5mm port **on your computer** is damaged. <strike>Try connecting the headset to another port or computer.</strike> - you said you already did, I didn't notice in the first place.

I bet it's the wire.